# insertBefore working on every all instances of that class despite this

Tags: jquery

Please review my fiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/sfcx0xvb/

How do I make the function work only within the element with that specific classname?

I thought .each did that, but it appears it doesn't.

As the .image-block gets inserted before all instances of .text-block, not just within article.alt as you can see in the fiddle.

Thanks!

HTML

```
<article>
<div class="image-block">
    <img src="http://stwww.bikemag.com/files/2013/04/KONA-7145.jpg" alt="Kona" />
</div><div class="text-block">
<p>
    in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
</article>


<article class="alt">
<div class="image-block">
    <img src="http://www.bikemag.com/files/2013/04/KONA-7145.jpg" alt="Kona" />
</div><div class="text-block">
<p>
    in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
article{
width:100%;
margin-bottom:1em;
}

.image-block, .text-block{
display:block;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:49%
}

.text-block{
vertical-align:top;
padding:1%;
}

img{
width:100%
}
```

JS:

```
$('article.alt').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.image-block').insertBefore('.text-block');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does. The problem is, you're losing context with the `insertBefore` selector, which is not told to look in the context of the current `this` element, but, rather, the entire DOM. Instead:

```
$(this).find('.image-block').insertBefore($(this).find('.text-block'));
```